# How to delete duplicate and original entries in either access or excel (multiple columns)

Tags: excel, ms-access

Is there a way to delete all duplicate rows and the original entry in either excel or access?
I need to delete whole rows that match in 3 columns. Here is a visual (Bottom table is what the table should become; in this case the duplicates + original with the same Part number, manufacturer and manufacture number are deleted): [image: VISUAL]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me in Access:

```sql
DELETE FROM parts
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT p2.[PART NUMBER], p2.[MANUFACTURER], p2.[MANUFACTURER NUMBER]
    FROM parts p2
    WHERE parts.[PART NUMBER] = p2.[PART NUMBER] 
        AND parts.[MANUFACTURER] = p2.[MANUFACTURER] 
        AND parts.[MANUFACTURER NUMBER] = p2.[MANUFACTURER NUMBER]
    GROUP BY p2.[PART NUMBER], p2.[MANUFACTURER], p2.[MANUFACTURER NUMBER]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

When I run it on my test data...

```
PART NUMBER  MANUFACTURER  QUALITY  MANUFACTURER NUMBER
-----------  ------------  -------  -------------------
123          GORD                1  750                
123          OTHER               3  321                
123          OTHER               4  321
```

...it deletes the two "OTHER" rows but leaves the "GORD" row alone.

Comment: You beat me to it while I was working it out. :-)  While similar, I think I like yours better.

Comment: Quick question... where do I input this so I can run it?

Comment: @Shivster In Access, click `Create > Query Design`, close the "Show Table" dialog (without adding anything), then on the `Query Tools / Design` tab of the ribbon click "SQL View". That should give you a blank window with `SELECT;` in it. Paste the code in there (replacing the existing `SELECT;`) and adjust the code as required. Oh, and **make sure you have a backup of your data** before experimenting with DELETE queries!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE * FROM MyTable WHERE PartNumber in (SELECT MyTable.PartNumber
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.PartNumber
HAVING (((Sum(1))>1)));
```

Comment: That won't work. He requested that it match on 3 fields, and you're using Sum where you should be using Count.

Comment: I hope you weren't the one who down-voted me, because if so you don't understand how Sum(1) works.

Comment: I was, but in testing I see that Sum acts like Count here. I learned something new. Your solution still doesn't match on 3 fields though. But if you edit your answer, I'll remove my down vote (the system won't let me otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you. It checks all three fields, and deletes the original and all duplicates.

```
DELETE 
  parts.* 
FROM parts 
WHERE  (( ((SELECT Count (*) 
            FROM   parts AS P 
            WHERE  ( P.partnum & P.manf & P.manfnum = 
                     parts.partnum & parts.manf & parts.manfnum ) 
                   AND ( P.partnum <= parts.partnum ))) > 1 ));
```